# How to do git push from bitbucket-pipelines.yml?

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration, package.json, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a node project. What I want to do is on a developer checkin (commit and push), I want to run the bitbucket pipeline which would internally do the following

1. npm install and npm test
2. npm version patch (to increment the version in the package.json)
3. git push origin master --follow-tags
4. npm publish

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
    image: node:8
    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm version patch
              - git push origin develop --follow-tags
              - npm publish
```

I am facing problem on the "git push origin master --follow-tags". How do I give pipeline the permission to push back to the repository?

Also I want to know if this will trigger a cycle, where my bitbucket pipeline executes again since I incremented the package.json version and did a check in (commit and push)?

What is the recommended way of doing CI/CD With version number increments on a nodejs project using bitbucket-pipelines?

Cheers,
Rohit

Comment: to add @crazko answer you can add "[skip ci]" or "[ci skip]" anywhere in you commit message and build will not run

Answer (score 8):

I was facing a similar problem, though not associated with nodejs development.

The reason a build fails on `git push` is that ssh key pair that you are able to generate under **Pipelines > SSH keys** settings doesn't have write access.

Delete generated pair and use your own that is connected to your account. You also have to create a commit before the push. Add to your **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**:

```
- git config user.email <your@email>
- git add package.json
- git commit -m "updated version"
```

The answer to your second question is: yes, it would trigger another build, as they are triggered on every commit by default. 
In my case, subsequent build produced the exact same output which made the whole build failed on `git commit`. It was up-to-date with origin, therefore stopped repetitive triggering.

It's not nice to have two builds on every change where one of them always fails.  A solution to this might be [running builds by hand](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/run-pipelines-manually-861242583.html) by adding the **custom** section into config.

Eventually, I abandoned this whole idea pushing back something with pipelines, because of lack of automation.

#### Updated

Now, there is also a possibility to [schedule builds](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/scheduled-pipelines-933078702.html). With this feature, repetitive triggering could be also avoided.

Comment: If you include  [skip ci] or [ci skip] anywhere in your commit message, it should not retrigger a build (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-pipelines-faq-827104769.html)

Comment: @crazko How would I pair my own SSH key that is connected to my account?

Comment: @AlejandroCotilla - I meant any SSH key that is added in your account settings in https://bitbucket.org/account under **SSH keys**

Comment: @crazko - Yes I know what you meant, and your answer was the solution to the problem I was having, but I was asking how would I then add my own account private ssh key to the Docker container, but I figured it out, I added it to the Docker image, and I have a script in my Dockerfile that copies the ssh key to the container when the pipeline runs.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue and wanted to expand on this to include a scenario where facing a private repo other than NPM.  It looks messy and if someone has a better way feel free to correct. You need a custom `.npmrc` in order to add the custom npm registry.  Then you need to clean everything afterwards after adding the new version.

The scenario below is placing the Node application within a VSTS package.

```
           script:
                - mv .npmrc_config .npmrc
                - git config --global push.default simple
                - git remote set-url origin https://${AUTH_STRING}@bitbucket.org/${COMPANY}/${REPO}.git
                - git config --global user.email "<YOUR EMAIL>"
                - git config --global user.name "<YOUR USERNAME>"
                - git add .npmrc
                - git rm .npmrc_config
                - git commit -m "[skip CI]"
                - git push origin master
                - npm install
                - npm version patch
                - git push origin master --follow-tags
                - npm publish
                - mv .npmrc .npmrc_config
                - git add .npmrc_config
                - git rm .npmrc
                - git commit -m "[skip CI]"
                - git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to push to a repo, you need to have write access. One way to achieve it is to use [access tokens](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/access-tokens/).

This will give you an access token and a mail address that you can use to pull/push code to a repository:

```
# Setup git
- git config --global user.email "${TOKEN_MAIL}"

# Clone the repo
- git clone https://x-token-auth:${ACCESS_TOKEN}@bitbucket.org/your/repo.git

# Git add, commit and push
- git add .
- git commit -m "Updated version"
- git push
```